# Flag Option: User is a troll

Tags: feature-request, flags

There has been a rash of troll posts on Stack Overflow recently. Can we get a new flag option to combat them?

The 'spam' flag isn't quite right due to the non-commercial nature of the posts. The *Other* / *Something not quite right* section has been pressed into this service, but is not very specific.

Comment: What's a troll? (Or, what's _your_ definition of a troll?)

Comment: is this a serious suggestion or just trolling?

Comment: @Yannis The recent spate of posts have followed a similar theme: they have been designed to waste the time of answerers without adding value to the site. I don't suppose that this is a one-size-fits all definition: In some ways, it falls into the "I know it when I see it" category which is less than ideal. Nevertheless, I am still convinced that the problem is pervasive enough to warrant a dedicated flag option.

Comment: @Yannis: There is one person that keeps creating new accounts, creating semi-serious questions that then devolve quickly as the troll ropes in people asking for clarifications. It's a real troll alright, but the regulars + moderators are handling the current outbreak just fine without a special flag.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Wasn't doubting there was a real problem, but as you mention these problems tend to fall into the "I know it when I see it" category. And we already have a flag for that (the custom one). I think a troll flag would be horribly abused, it'll generate tons and tons of spiteful flags (of the "he voted to close my question, the f'ing troll" variety).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - Just to let you know, I feel your frustration. Almost all of these recent trolling posts are due to one individual who we're all well aware of. We're trying to catch them as they create new accounts, but they are the most determined (or bored) troll I've ever seen. Beyond this one person, trolls tend to be uncommon enough (compared to spammers) that the "other" or "offensive" flags work very well in identifying them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Flag with `other` and include a brief message. Especially with new trolls it helps that you present a little evidence, a generic 'User is a troll' flag would not give you that opportunity.

We're handling the current troll just fine with that.

Comment: Yes; in a case such as the one recently, a simple "troll is back" will do. I assure you, all the mods know of 'that guy'. His names usually are a dead giveaway, too. That said, I don't decline the Spam or Offensive flags I see from him, either.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on the post, not the intention behind it. If someone posts a nonsensical question just to get attention, downvote and close the post as "Not a real question", because that is the flaw in the question.

Typically, this kind of problem resolves itself within one or two questions, since a post ban kicks in unless the user gets their act together really quick. You can flag for moderator attention as well if the post warrants it, in which case you should leave a custom description.

Regarding your feature request, I feel if the option were added there would be an insane number of knee-jerk "troll" flags, given how the term has come to apply to almost anyone you don't like on the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes you have no option but to focus on the person and not on the content. However, I do feel that a troll flag would _encourage_ people to focus on the person instead of on the content, and that wouldn't be good.

Comment: @Yannis Right, but there's a subtle difference between focusing on the user and trying to determine the intentions of a user. There's nothing wrong with flagging a bad post if you've seen the user post multiple crappy questions or lots of spam before, but trying to ascertain whether they were trolling or legitimately naive is a long shot at best.

Comment: If the OP here is talking about whom I think he is talking, then in this *specific* case problem is definitely the user. The regulars now quickly recognize the user's latest accounts and don't bother engaging the user anymore. I vote to close the question, downvote it, and flag it for mod attention. Then find out what other questions already have been posted and vote to close those too. Then move on with my day.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I have no problems with that. See my previous comment.